# -webkit-transform: scale() not displaying properly in OSX Safari

Tags: html, macos, safari, css, scaling

I've been tasked with fixing a bug in our product for Safari 5.05 for OSX where a loaded preview of another page (iframe) isn't scaled properly. What's odd is that it works in Safari for windows, aswell as Safari for the ipad.

The iframe is cut in half on OSX, and changing the width of the wrapper div really doesn't do any good. If I change scale to 1, or remove the -webkit-transform from css, the iframe is fully rendered (but not scaled down).

How it looks in just about any browser except OSX Safari 5.05:

How it looks in Safari on Windows and iPad and just about any version of Chrome:

[image]

And the OSX Safari version:

[image]

```
<div id="newsletterPreview" class="scaleDownPreview" style="-webkit-transform: translate(-157px, -267px) scale(0.6); ">
    <iframe style="width: 1338.3333333333335px; height: 1333px; " frameborder="0" src="controls/NewsletterPreview.ashx?skipIframe=true">
        [bla bla bla]
    </iframe>
</div>

.scaleDownPreview {
    zoom: 0.6;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by setting the zoom level to the iframe content rather than the iframe element.

I fixed in my Rails app a like this.

```
<iframe src="/?zoom=0.5" />
```

And then on that page just styled it like this.

```
<% if params[:zoom] %>

 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  html {
    -moz-transform: scale(<%= params[:zoom] %>);
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -webkit-transform: scale(<%= params[:zoom] %>);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    transform: scale(<%= params[:zoom] %>);
    transform-origin: left top;
    zoom: <%= params[:zoom] %>;
  }
</style>

<% end %>
```

One could do the same thing with javascript by just reaching into the iframe styling the html element.

Comment: Awesome, I'll check it out when I get back to work on monday . Happy midsummers eve from Sweden.

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks!
You can set the html-attribute with jQuery using $('iframe').contents().find('html').css( [...] )

Do take note that the iframe isn't necessarily loaded when using document ready. Workaround is to load the iframe using $().load() and use the callback. But I decided to just set all of it in code behind (using asp.net) to avoid fouc.